# How to trigger a function when the redux state is changed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm creating a login page that requires users to input CAPTCHA strings.

The following is my code.

I have a redux state `isFail` with the default value `false`. Once the user fails to login, the state will become `true`.

When the `isFail` becomes true, I want it to trigger `fetchCaptcha()` function to refresh the captcha image.

Is there any better way to trigger the function of redux state change?

```js
const LoginForm = props => {
    const captchaImage = useSelector(state => state.auth.captchaImage);
    const isFail = useSelector(state => state.auth.isFail);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const fetchCaptcha = useCallback(() => dispatch(actions.fetchCaptcha()), [dispatch]);
    const login = useCallback(data => dispatch(actions.login(data)), [dispatch]);

    const loginHandler = (formData) => {
        login(formData);
        
        if(isFail){
          fetchCaptcha();
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchCaptcha();
    }, [fetchCaptcha]);

    return (
      ...SKIP
    );
  }
  
  export default LoginForm;
```

Comment: It looks like what you really want is to modify the action that changes the isFail state to dispatch the fetchCaptcha action as well

Comment: @DanPantry The action that changes `isFail` is `login()`. So I should trigger `fetchCaptcha()` in `login()` if user login fails, is it what you mean? I am just afraid that whether it makes bad smell to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `store.subscribe(callbackFunction)`. It will be called any time an action is dispatched.

https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener

Comment: Could you advise where I should add subscribe() function in my code ?